# Concatinating array in php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to concatenate two arrays on same level (into a new array) with keys on those values. Have tried this so far:

```
$car_all_attributes = array();
            foreach ($cars_without_price as $key => $cars) 
            {
                $keep_fare = 0;
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($data['cars_fare'] as $f_key => $fare) 
                {
                    $c_fare = (explode("-",$fare));
                    if ($c_fare[0] == $cars->chauffeur_id) 
                    {
                        $car_fare = $c_fare[1];
                        $car_all_attributes[$f_key]['old_price'] = $car_fare;
                        $car_all_attributes[$f_key][$key] = $cars;
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

And result i get is little off which i want it to do, the result i get is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [old_price] => 460
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [chauffeur_id] => 16
                [chauffeur_avalibality] => 1
                [chauffeur_supplier_id] => 1
                [chauffeur_country_id] => 190
                [chauffeur_city_id] => 0
                [chauffeur_make] => Mercedes S 350 or similar
                [chauffeur_model] => 
                [chauffeur_car_type] => 2
                [chauffeur_transmission] => 
                [chauffeur_door] => 4
                [chauffeur_passengers] => 5
                [chauffeur_large_suitecase] => 4
                [chauffeur_small_suitecase] => 5
                [chauffeur_ac] => 1
                [chauffeur_img] => carType_145851015451.jpg
                [chauffeur_service_chaufer] => 1
                [chauffeur_service_airport] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [old_price] => 352
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [chauffeur_id] => 17
                [chauffeur_avalibality] => 1
                [chauffeur_supplier_id] => 1
                [chauffeur_country_id] => 190
                [chauffeur_city_id] => 0
                [chauffeur_make] => Mercedes E-Class or similar
                [chauffeur_model] => 
                [chauffeur_car_type] => 1
                [chauffeur_transmission] => 
                [chauffeur_door] => 4
                [chauffeur_passengers] => 4
                [chauffeur_large_suitecase] => 4
                [chauffeur_small_suitecase] => 4
                [chauffeur_ac] => 0
                [chauffeur_img] => carType_145851017815.jpg
                [chauffeur_service_chaufer] => 1
                [chauffeur_service_airport] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [old_price] => 368
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [chauffeur_id] => 18
                [chauffeur_avalibality] => 1
                [chauffeur_supplier_id] => 1
                [chauffeur_country_id] => 190
                [chauffeur_city_id] => 0
                [chauffeur_make] => Mercedes Viano or similar
                [chauffeur_model] => 
                [chauffeur_car_type] => 3
                [chauffeur_transmission] => 
                [chauffeur_door] => 4
                [chauffeur_passengers] => 6
                [chauffeur_large_suitecase] => 4
                [chauffeur_small_suitecase] => 6
                [chauffeur_ac] => 1
                [chauffeur_img] => carType_145851020593.jpg
                [chauffeur_service_chaufer] => 1
                [chauffeur_service_airport] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
            )

    )
```

)
I don't want this `[0]=>stdClass Object` while assigning, i know i'm doing `$car_all_attributes[$f_key][$key]` and a new key get's added and all values against it, was wondering if there's a way to do it on same level like the result array would look like this ?

```
[0] => Array
    (
                [old_price] => 460
                [chauffeur_id] => 16
                [chauffeur_avalibality] => 1
                [chauffeur_supplier_id] => 1
                [chauffeur_country_id] => 190
                [chauffeur_city_id] => 0
                [chauffeur_make] => Mercedes S 350 or similar
                [chauffeur_model] => 
                [chauffeur_car_type] => 2
                [chauffeur_transmission] => 
                [chauffeur_door] => 4
                [chauffeur_passengers] => 5
                [chauffeur_large_suitecase] => 4
                [chauffeur_small_suitecase] => 5
                [chauffeur_ac] => 1
                [chauffeur_img] => carType_145851015451.jpg
                [chauffeur_service_chaufer] => 1
                [chauffeur_service_airport] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$car_all_attributes[$f_key]['old_price'] = $car_fare;
$car_all_attributes[$f_key][$key] = $cars;
```

try this (i.e convert object into array and merge it with old price instead of adding a new key)-

```
$car_all_attributes[$f_key] = array_merge(
     array('old_price' => $car_fare), 
     (array) $cars
);
```

Comment: Yes, this is spot on. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `$cars` is an object. You should fetch an array instead or convert it into an array.

```
if ($c_fare[0] == $cars->chauffeur_id) {
    $car_fare = $c_fare[1];
    $car_all_attributes[$f_key] = (array)$cars;
    $car_all_attributes[$f_key]['old_price'] = $car_fare;
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$car_all_attributes[$f_key][$key] = $cars;
```

to

```
$car_all_attributes[$f_key] = (array)$cars;
```